# the output array shows only the last element instead of inserting data at specified location in the array

Tags: c++, arrays

```
        cout<<"The array after insertion is as follows: "<<endl;
        for(i=0;i<n;i++){
            cout<<items[n]<<endl;
```

**objective** is to insert an user desired element in an array at user desired location such that the array

**instead** the array displays the final element in a loop as image below

[image: output]

Comment: Please avoid posting images when pasting result would be more relevant. Bad practice here.

Comment: `cin>>items[n];` and the corresponding output later is wrong. Use `[i]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two issues:

1. `cin>>items[n];`  must be `cin>>items[i];`
2. `cout<<items[n]<<endl;` must be `cout<<items[i]<<endl;`